# Fachbegriff für das Weglassen von Termen, die den Wert 0 haben?

Tags: single-word-request, technical-terminology, mathematics

Ich suche einen Fachbegriff aus der Mathematik.
Ihr wisst schon, wenn ich eine Gleichung habe (z.B. a = b + c), und ich weiß dass c = 0, dann kann ich c auch weglassen.

Gibt es für diese Vereinfachung einen Fachbegriff? (Ähnlich wie Kürzen bei Brüchen?)

Ein Beispiel könnte lauten:

> Stellen Sie die Maschengleichung für die Masche M1 auf. Stellen Sie die Gleichung nach U1 um. Vernachlässigen Sie [hier sollte der gesuchte Begriff anstatt "Vernachlässigen" stehen] alle Spannungen, die den Wert 0 haben.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ein allgemeinerer Ausdruck, den man vielleicht benutzen könnte, wäre "eliminieren". Das Wort benutzt man normalerweise dafür, dass man Variablen, die nicht benötigt werden, aus einer Gleichung entfernt, zum Beispiel durch Substitution.

Hier wird halt speziell mit 0 substituiert - aber dazu muss man ja im Allgemeinen auch erst mal wissen (oder berechnen), welche Variablen 0 sind.

Answer (score 5):

Zunächst einmal klingt es für mich seltsam explizit zu erwähnen, dass Terme identisch null weggelassen werden sollen. Man könnte also überlegen es einfach gar nicht zu erwähnen. Andererseits habe ich Studenten schon deutlich merkwürdigere Dinge machen sehen und wenn das in der Vergangenheit bei Klausuren oder Übungsblättern schon zu Verwirrung geführt hat, ist ein expliziteres Hinschreiben sicherlich nicht verkehrt.

Vernachlässigen kann man meines Erachtens nach nur relativ kleine Terme (beispielsweise lineare Terme wenn es Terme höherer Ordnung gibt und man diese für große Zahlen betrachtet). In diesem Falle ist es einfach ein weglassen.

Mein Vorschlag ist, den Satz positiv umzuformulieren

> Stellen Sie die Maschengleichung in Abhängigkeit aller nicht verschwindenden Spannungen auf.

Answer (score 3):

In der Schule, im Mathe- oder Physikunterricht, lautete die entsprechende Anweisung immer:

> Vereinfachen Sie den Term so weit wie möglich.

Das ist strenggenommen nicht spezifisch für das Eliminieren verschwindender Terme. Für den Anwendungsfall in deinem Beispiel scheint es mir aber dennoch der beste Ausdruck.

Answer (score 2):

In deinem Beispiel schreibst du:

> Vernachlässigen Sie alle Spannungen, die den Wert 0 haben.

Statt »Vernachlässigen« könnte man hier »Tilgen« verwenden. Ist natürlich kein Fachbegriff.

Answer (score 1):

Du könntest das Wort *verschwinden* verwenden. Z. B. so:

> Es gilt a = b + c , und da c verschwindet, ergibt sich a = b .

*Vernachlässigen* bedeutet etwas anderes: Es wird approximiert, indem man kleine Terme wegläßt.

Answer (score 0):

Dafür gibt es keinen allgemein verwendeten Fachbegriff. In einer Gleichung (wie einer Maschengleichung) wird eine Beziehung zwischen verschiedenen Größen präzise beschrieben. Normalerweise haben alle auftretenden Variablen darin ihren Sinn und können je nach konkreter Situation von Null verschiedene Werte annehmen. In gewissen speziellen Situationen können jedoch *Randbedingungen* gegeben sein, die einer oder mehreren Variablen den Wert 0 zuweisen. In diesem Fall kann man natürlich die allgemeine Gleichung durch Weglassen dieser Variablen vereinfachen und sollte dies genauso formulieren. Also:

- Stellen Sie die Maschengleichung für die Masche M1 auf. Stellen Sie die Gleichung nach U1 um. Vereinfachen Sie die Gleichung durch Weglassen aller Spannungen, die den Wert 0 haben.

In der Frage wird auch auf den Fachbegriff "Kürzen von Brüchen" Bezug genommen. Der Unterschied zum Weglassen von Variablen ist, dass Kürzen ohne jegliche zusätzliche Randbedingung möglich ist.